# Evaluating whether a function is a probability density or not

Tags: probability

I would like to have my solution checked and gather some further information. I have to show which of the following functions define a probability density. We work with $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $f: \Omega \rightarrow \Bbb R$.

Now, for a function being a probability density, we have to check if the values $f(i) = p_i \in$ $[0, 1]$ and if the sum of these values equals $1$.

$f(i)$ = $i \over 5$ is not a probabilty density. Although $p_i \in [0, 1]$, the sum of the $p_i$ doesn't equal $1$, but $6 \over 5$.

$f(i) =$ ${i + 1} \over 9$ is a probality density since $p_i \in [0, 1]$ and since the sum of the $p_i$ does indeed equal $1$.

$f(i) = (-1)^{i+1}$ is not a probality density. For $i = 2$, we receive $f(2) = -1 \notin [0, 1]$.

$f(i) = 2 - i$ is not a probality density either. For $i = 3$, we receive $f(3) = -1 \notin [0, 1]$.

Somehow, this seems way too easy for me. Is it correct so far?

Furthermore, for the second case, I have to evaluate the propability measure, but isn't it given by the function itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your answers are correct. Presumably, it is easy because it is just your first introduction to the subject (and will get harder). Without context, it is difficult to say what it means to "evaluate" a probability measure; the closest I can think of is that they want you to make a table of function arguments and values, but that is really quite trivial and not insightful.

Comment: Well, that might have been a bad translation of mine. I guess the correct term I have to use here is "specify the propability measure".

Comment: In that case, they probably want you to give the probability $P(A)$ for any subset $A \subseteq \Omega$.

Comment: For example like $P(\{1, 2\})$ $=$ $5 \over 9$? Or is there a way to specify this for an arbitrary subset?

Comment: Yes, like that. The "general way" to specificy it would be something like $P(A) = \sum_{i \in A} \frac{i+1}9$, but that is so much like writing down the definition that I would argue it doesn't qualify as an answer to the question.

Comment: Will ask the tutor on that one, thank you!